# IBM WebSphere Application Server ND 7.0 installer on a Debian Jessie AMD64 KVM host stuck on generateProfileKey

Tags: debian, kvm-virtualization, websphere

I am trying to install IBM WebSphere Application Server Network Deployment version 7.0 on an AMD64 KVM VM running Debian Jessie. I cannot start the launchpad.sh script regardless of whether I use Debian Iceweasel from APT or Mozilla Firefox manually installed, but I can start the installer by running `<WAS installer directory/WAS/install`. However, when attempting to install a cell profile (the one with nodeagent and deployment manager), the installer stays stuck on a post-extraction step called "generateProfileKey" and will not proceed any further. I already made sure the installer is running off its own bundled JRE instead of my system's OpenJDK JRE.

Any idea of why this happens and what can I do to make this step complete successfully?

---

**Update:** I tried attaching `strace` to the installer process, which is a Java app. When the installer gets stuck on the generateProfileKey step, `strace` shows a lot of stuff like this:

```
[pid 15506] futex(0x7fd7c4b9bb14, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE|FUTEX_CLOCK_REALTIME, 128811, {1444774068, 879328000}, ffffffff) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
[pid 15506] futex(0x7fd7c4b9bb40, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
[pid 15506] gettimeofday({1444774068, 879537}, {300, 1444774068}) = 0
[pid 15506] gettimeofday({1444774068, 879569}, {300, 1444774068}) = 0
[pid 15506] gettimeofday({1444774068, 879588}, NULL) = 0
[pid 15506] futex(0x7fd7c4b9bb14, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE|FUTEX_CLOCK_REALTIME, 128813, {1444774068, 884588000}, ffffffff) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
[pid 15506] futex(0x7fd7c4b9bb40, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
[pid 15506] gettimeofday({1444774068, 884815}, {300, 1444774068}) = 0
[pid 15506] gettimeofday({1444774068, 884844}, {300, 1444774068}) = 0
[pid 15506] gettimeofday({1444774068, 884860}, NULL) = 0
[pid 15506] futex(0x7fd7c4b9bb14, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE|FUTEX_CLOCK_REALTIME, 128815, {1444774068, 889860000}, ffffffff) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
[pid 15506] futex(0x7fd7c4b9bb40, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
[pid 15506] gettimeofday({1444774068, 890061}, {300, 1444774068}) = 0
[pid 15506] gettimeofday({1444774068, 890092}, {300, 1444774068}) = 0
[pid 15506] gettimeofday({1444774068, 890111}, NULL) = 0
```

Next are the last few log messages created by the installer when it got stuck on the offending step. Since it seems like the last log file has a detailed trace of the profile invocation and key generation process, I'm going to start over the installation focusing on file `/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/logs/manageprofiles/Dmgr01_create.log`.

**/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/logs/install/installconfig.log**

```
<record>
    <date>Oct 13, 2015 5:01:27 PM</date>
    <millis>1444773687650</millis>
    <sequence>2537</sequence>
    <logger>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.ConfigManager</logger>
    <level>INFO</level>
    <class>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.ConfigManager</class>
    <method>executeAllActionsFound</method>
    <thread>4</thread>
    <message>Configuration action succeeded: com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ConfigAction-/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/properties/version/nif/config/install/95SCIMRepository.ijc</message>
</record>
<record>
    <date>Oct 13, 2015 5:01:27 PM</date>
    <millis>1444773687662</millis>
    <sequence>2540</sequence>
    <logger>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.IJCAction</logger>
    <level>INFO</level>
    <class>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.IJCAction</class>
    <method>getClassNameForThisAction</method>
    <thread>4</thread>
    <message>Class to launch for /usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/properties/version/nif/config/install/97SInstallInvokeWSProfile.ijc is: com.ibm.ws.install.config.actions.InstallInvokeWSProfileConfigAction</message>
</record>
<record>
    <date>Oct 13, 2015 5:01:27 PM</date>
    <millis>1444773687759</millis>
    <sequence>2541</sequence>
    <logger>com.ibm.ws.install.config.actions.InstallInvokeWSProfileConfigAction</logger>
    <level>INFO</level>
    <class>com.ibm.ws.install.config.actions.InstallInvokeWSProfileConfigAction</class>
    <method>logPassingParameters</method>
    <thread>4</thread>
    <message>Installer is invoking WSProfile [/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/properties/version/nif/config/script/invokeactions.sh, -create, -adminPassword, ****************, -adminUserName, kyoko, -samplesPassword, ****************, -templatePath, /usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profileTemplates/cell, -enableAdminSecurity, true, 47782]</message>
</record>
```

**/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/logs/manageprofiles/create.log**

```
<record>
    <date>Oct 13, 2015 5:01:40 PM</date>
    <millis>1444773700960</millis>
    <sequence>1079</sequence>
    <logger>com.ibm.ws.profile.WSConfigCreator</logger>
    <level>INFO</level>
    <class>com.ibm.ws.profile.WSConfigCreator</class>
    <method>buildCommandData</method>
    <thread>0</thread>
    <message>Generated Command data Dmgr: { "-cellName" ,"mitakiharaCell01" ,"-adminPassword" ,"********" ,"-profileName" ,"Dmgr01" ,"-adminUserName" ,"kyoko" ,"-appServerNodeName" ,"mitakiharaNode01" ,"-create" ,"-enableAdminSecurity" ,"true" ,"-nodeName" ,"mitakiharaCellManager01" ,"-templatePath" ,"/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profileTemplates/cell/dmgr" ,"-samplesPassword" ,"********" ,"-profilePath" ,"/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/Dmgr01" ,"-nodeProfilePath" ,"/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01" }</message>
</record>
<record>
    <date>Oct 13, 2015 5:01:40 PM</date>
    <millis>1444773700961</millis>
    <sequence>1080</sequence>
    <logger>com.ibm.ws.profile.utils.WSProfileUtils</logger>
    <level>INFO</level>
    <class>com.ibm.ws.profile.utils.WSProfileUtils</class>
    <method>getMaskableArgs</method>
    <thread>0</thread>
    <message>Maskable Action Arguments: { "winservicePassword" ,"adminPassword" ,"dmgrAdminPassword" ,"samplesPassword" ,"password" ,"adminPwd" ,"keyStorePassword" ,"importPersonalCertKSPassword" ,"importSigningCertKSPassword" ,"importDefaultCertKSPassword" ,"importRootCertKSPassword" }</message>
</record>
<record>
    <date>Oct 13, 2015 5:01:40 PM</date>
    <millis>1444773700962</millis>
    <sequence>1081</sequence>
    <logger>com.ibm.ws.profile.WSConfigCreator</logger>
    <level>INFO</level>
    <class>com.ibm.ws.profile.WSConfigCreator</class>
    <method>buildCommandData</method>
    <thread>0</thread>
    <message>Generated Command data Node: { "-cellName" ,"mitakiharaCell01" ,"-adminPassword" ,"********" ,"-adminUserName" ,"kyoko" ,"-appServerNodeName" ,"mitakiharaNode01" ,"-create" ,"-enableAdminSecurity" ,"true" ,"-profileName" ,"AppSrv01" ,"-nodeName" ,"mitakiharaCellManager01" ,"-templatePath" ,"/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profileTemplates/cell/default" ,"-samplesPassword" ,"********" ,"-profilePath" ,"/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01" ,"-dmgrProfilePath" ,"/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/Dmgr01" ,"-portsFile" ,"/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/Dmgr01/properties/portdef.props" ,"-nodePortsFile" ,"/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/Dmgr01/properties/nodeportdef.props" }</message>
</record>
<record>
    <date>Oct 13, 2015 5:01:40 PM</date>
    <millis>1444773700963</millis>
    <sequence>1082</sequence>
    <logger>com.ibm.ws.profile.WSConfigCreator</logger>
    <level>INFO</level>
    <class>com.ibm.ws.profile.WSConfigCreator</class>
    <method>runWSProfile</method>
    <thread>0</thread>
    <message>Generated WSProfileCommand Dmgr: [Ljava.lang.String;@5b005b0</message>
</record>
<record>
    <date>Oct 13, 2015 5:01:40 PM</date>
    <millis>1444773700963</millis>
    <sequence>1083</sequence>
    <logger>com.ibm.ws.profile.WSConfigCreator</logger>
    <level>INFO</level>
    <class>com.ibm.ws.profile.WSConfigCreator</class>
    <method>runWSProfile</method>
    <thread>0</thread>
    <message>Generated WSProfileCommand Node: [Ljava.lang.String;@5ca05ca</message>
</record>
```

**/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/logs/manageprofiles/Dmgr01_create.log**

```
<record>
    <date>Oct 13, 2015 5:02:30 PM</date>
    <millis>1444773750406</millis>
    <sequence>3475</sequence>
    <logger>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.ConfigManager</logger>
    <level>INFO</level>
    <class>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.ConfigManager</class>
    <method>executeAllActionsFound</method>
    <thread>0</thread>
    <message>Configuration action succeeded: com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ConfigAction-/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profileTemplates/cell/dmgr/actions/launchWsAdminListener.ant</message>
</record>
<record>
    <date>Oct 13, 2015 5:02:30 PM</date>
    <millis>1444773750407</millis>
    <sequence>3476</sequence>
    <logger>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ANTAction</logger>
    <level>INFO</level>
    <class>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ANTAction</class>
    <method>executeAction</method>
    <thread>0</thread>
    <message>Using an InProcess ANT call to execute this action: /usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profileTemplates/cell/dmgr/actions/generateProfileKey.ant</message>
</record>
<record>
    <date>Oct 13, 2015 5:02:30 PM</date>
    <millis>1444773750409</millis>
    <sequence>3477</sequence>
    <logger>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ant.utils.InProcessAntRunner</logger>
    <level>INFO</level>
    <class>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ant.utils.InProcessAntRunner</class>
    <method>logOutputMessage</method>
    <thread>0</thread>
    <message>Buildfile: /usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profileTemplates/cell/dmgr/actions/generateProfileKey.ant</message>
</record>
<record>
    <date>Oct 13, 2015 5:02:30 PM</date>
    <millis>1444773750410</millis>
    <sequence>3478</sequence>
    <logger>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ant.utils.ANTLogToCmtLogAdapter</logger>
    <level>INFO</level>
    <class>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ant.utils.ANTLogToCmtLogAdapter</class>
    <method>buildStarted</method>
    <thread>0</thread>
    <message>Build started.</message>
</record>
<record>
    <date>Oct 13, 2015 5:02:30 PM</date>
    <millis>1444773750531</millis>
    <sequence>3479</sequence>
    <logger>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ant.utils.AntTaskToLogToConfigManagersLogFiles</logger>
    <level>INFO</level>
    <class>/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profileTemplates/cell/dmgr/actions/generateProfileKey.ant:6: </class>
    <method></method>
    <thread>0</thread>
    <message> The current template path is: /usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profileTemplates/cell/dmgr</message>
</record>
<record>
    <date>Oct 13, 2015 5:02:30 PM</date>
    <millis>1444773750532</millis>
    <sequence>3480</sequence>
    <logger>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ant.utils.ANTLogToCmtLogAdapter</logger>
    <level>INFO</level>
    <class>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ant.utils.ANTLogToCmtLogAdapter</class>
    <method>targetStarted</method>
    <thread>0</thread>
    <message>Target started for: generateProfileKey</message>
</record>
<record>
    <date>Oct 13, 2015 5:02:30 PM</date>
    <millis>1444773750533</millis>
    <sequence>3481</sequence>
    <logger>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ant.utils.AntTaskToLogToConfigManagersLogFiles</logger>
    <level>INFO</level>
    <class>/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profileTemplates/cell/dmgr/actions/generateProfileKey.ant:12: </class>
    <method>generateProfileKey</method>
    <thread>0</thread>
    <message>Generate a profile key for the profile /usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/Dmgr01 with a profileTytpe DeploymentManager</message>
</record>
<record>
    <date>Oct 13, 2015 5:02:30 PM</date>
    <millis>1444773750538</millis>
    <sequence>3482</sequence>
    <logger>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ant.utils.ANTLogToCmtLogAdapter</logger>
    <level>INFO</level>
    <class>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ant.utils.ANTLogToCmtLogAdapter</class>
    <method>messageLogged</method>
    <thread>0</thread>
    <message>replacing value for local.node (null) with (mitakiharaCellManager01)</message>
</record>
<record>
    <date>Oct 13, 2015 5:02:30 PM</date>
    <millis>1444773750538</millis>
    <sequence>3483</sequence>
    <logger>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ant.utils.ANTLogToCmtLogAdapter</logger>
    <level>INFO</level>
    <class>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ant.utils.ANTLogToCmtLogAdapter</class>
    <method>messageLogged</method>
    <thread>0</thread>
    <message>replacing value for local.cell (null) with (mitakiharaCell01)</message>
</record>
<record>
    <date>Oct 13, 2015 5:02:30 PM</date>
    <millis>1444773750539</millis>
    <sequence>3484</sequence>
    <logger>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ant.utils.ANTLogToCmtLogAdapter</logger>
    <level>INFO</level>
    <class>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ant.utils.ANTLogToCmtLogAdapter</class>
    <method>messageLogged</method>
    <thread>0</thread>
    <message>replacing value for user.install.root (/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer) with (/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/Dmgr01)</message>
</record>
<record>
    <date>Oct 13, 2015 5:02:30 PM</date>
    <millis>1444773750539</millis>
    <sequence>3485</sequence>
    <logger>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ant.utils.ANTLogToCmtLogAdapter</logger>
    <level>INFO</level>
    <class>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ant.utils.ANTLogToCmtLogAdapter</class>
    <method>messageLogged</method>
    <thread>0</thread>
    <message>replacing value for was.install.root (/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer) with (/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer)</message>
</record>
<record>
    <date>Oct 13, 2015 5:02:30 PM</date>
    <millis>1444773750539</millis>
    <sequence>3486</sequence>
    <logger>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ant.utils.ANTLogToCmtLogAdapter</logger>
    <level>INFO</level>
    <class>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ant.utils.ANTLogToCmtLogAdapter</class>
    <method>messageLogged</method>
    <thread>0</thread>
    <message>replacing value for was.repository.root (null) with (/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/Dmgr01/config)</message>
</record>
<record>
    <date>Oct 13, 2015 5:02:30 PM</date>
    <millis>1444773750539</millis>
    <sequence>3487</sequence>
    <logger>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ant.utils.ANTLogToCmtLogAdapter</logger>
    <level>INFO</level>
    <class>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ant.utils.ANTLogToCmtLogAdapter</class>
    <method>messageLogged</method>
    <thread>0</thread>
    <message>replacing value for com.ibm.ws.scripting.wsadminprops (null) with (/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/Dmgr01/properties/wsadmin.properties)</message>
</record>
<record>
    <date>Oct 13, 2015 5:02:30 PM</date>
    <millis>1444773750573</millis>
    <sequence>3488</sequence>
    <logger>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ant.utils.ANTLogToCmtLogAdapter</logger>
    <level>INFO</level>
    <class>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ant.utils.ANTLogToCmtLogAdapter</class>
    <method>messageLogged</method>
    <thread>0</thread>
    <message>Resetting listener available status to: false</message>
</record>
<record>
    <date>Oct 13, 2015 5:02:30 PM</date>
    <millis>1444773750574</millis>
    <sequence>3489</sequence>
    <logger>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ant.utils.ANTLogToCmtLogAdapter</logger>
    <level>INFO</level>
    <class>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ant.utils.ANTLogToCmtLogAdapter</class>
    <method>messageLogged</method>
    <thread>0</thread>
    <message>setting wsadmin requester timeouts</message>
</record>
<record>
    <date>Oct 13, 2015 5:02:30 PM</date>
    <millis>1444773750575</millis>
    <sequence>3490</sequence>
    <logger>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ant.utils.ANTLogToCmtLogAdapter</logger>
    <level>INFO</level>
    <class>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ant.utils.ANTLogToCmtLogAdapter</class>
    <method>messageLogged</method>
    <thread>0</thread>
    <message>wsadmin requester retry count = 240000, initialization retry count = 12000, shutdown retry count = 12000</message>
</record>
<record>
    <date>Oct 13, 2015 5:02:30 PM</date>
    <millis>1444773750576</millis>
    <sequence>3491</sequence>
    <logger>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ant.utils.ANTLogToCmtLogAdapter</logger>
    <level>INFO</level>
    <class>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ant.utils.ANTLogToCmtLogAdapter</class>
    <method>messageLogged</method>
    <thread>0</thread>
    <message>Checking for wsadmin listener initialization</message>
</record>
```

---

**Update 2:** I let the profile key creation process complete, and now I have a full trace of the failed profile creation. The trace, as expected, was on `/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/logs/manageprofiles/Dmgr01_create.log`. Since it's a pretty long error trace written in XML, I'm only showing here the result of only leaving the contents of the `<message>` elements.

The error seems to be caused by a failing ANT build. I'm not a Java developer (I intend to use WAS as middleware for IBM Cognos Business Intelligence) so I have never used ANT before, but it seems like the next step is to try and debug the ANT build on `/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profileTemplates/cell/dmgr/actions/generateProfileKey.ant`

**/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/logs/manageprofiles/Dmgr01_create.log**

```
Using an InProcess ANT call to execute this action: /usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profileTemplates/cell/dmgr/actions/generateProfileKey.ant
Buildfile: /usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profileTemplates/cell/dmgr/actions/generateProfileKey.ant
Build started.
 The current template path is: /usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profileTemplates/cell/dmgr
Target started for: generateProfileKey
Generate a profile key for the profile /usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/Dmgr01 with a profileTytpe DeploymentManager
replacing value for local.node (null) with (mitakiharaCellManager01)
replacing value for local.cell (null) with (mitakiharaCell01)
replacing value for user.install.root (/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer) with (/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/Dmgr01)
replacing value for was.install.root (/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer) with (/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer)
replacing value for was.repository.root (null) with (/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/Dmgr01/config)
replacing value for com.ibm.ws.scripting.wsadminprops (null) with (/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/Dmgr01/properties/wsadmin.properties)
Resetting listener available status to: false
setting wsadmin requester timeouts
wsadmin requester retry count = 240000, initialization retry count = 12000, shutdown retry count = 12000
Checking for wsadmin listener initialization

----------- (Almost an entire hour later...) -----------

Is wsadmin listener available? false
Returning with returnCode=-1
Failure detected in fatal config action.
Signalling wsadmin listener to stop.
wsadmin failed with exception = wsadmin task failed with return code :-1
wsadmin task failed with return code :-1
   at com.ibm.ws.ant.utils.ProjectUtils.reportError(ProjectUtils.java:30)
   at com.ibm.websphere.ant.tasks.WsAdminInProcess.execute(WsAdminInProcess.java:326)
   at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:275)
   at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:364)
   at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:341)
   at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:369)
   at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1216)
   at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1185)
   at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:40)
   at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1068)
   at com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ant.utils.InProcessAntRunner.runBuild(InProcessAntRunner.java:785)
   at com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ant.utils.InProcessAntRunner.start(InProcessAntRunner.java:234)
   at com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ANTAction.executeActionUsingAnInProcessANTCall(ANTAction.java:107)
   at com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ANTAction.executeAction(ANTAction.java:54)
   at com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ConfigAction.executeAction(ConfigAction.java:95)
   at com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.ConfigManager.executeAllActionsFound(ConfigManager.java:956)
   at com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.ConfigManager.executeActions(ConfigManager.java:565)
   at com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.ConfigManager.launch(ConfigManager.java:327)
   at com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.launcher.Launcher.mainForInProcessCMTCallers(Launcher.java:65)
   at com.ibm.wsspi.profile.WSProfile.doCreate(WSProfile.java:404)
   at com.ibm.wsspi.profile.WSProfile.create(WSProfile.java:224)
   at com.ibm.ws.profile.cli.WSProfileCLICreateProfileInvoker.executeWSProfileAccordingToMode(WSProfileCLICreateProfileInvoker.java:255)
   at com.ibm.ws.profile.cli.WSProfileCLIModeInvoker.invokeWSProfile(WSProfileCLIModeInvoker.java:462)
   at com.ibm.ws.profile.WSProfileJob.run(WSProfileJob.java:94)
   at com.ibm.ws.profile.utils.WSProfileUtils.executeAllJobs(WSProfileUtils.java:793)
   at com.ibm.ws.profile.utils.WSProfileUtils.executeAllJobs(WSProfileUtils.java:793)
   at com.ibm.wsspi.profile.WSProfileCLI.invokeWSProfile(WSProfileCLI.java:199)
   at com.ibm.wsspi.profile.WSProfileCLI.mainForInProcessCalls(WSProfileCLI.java:90)
   at com.ibm.ws.profile.WSConfigCreator.runWSProfile(WSConfigCreator.java:728)
   at com.ibm.ws.profile.WSConfigCreator.mainForInProcessCalls(WSConfigCreator.java:99)
   at com.ibm.ws.install.config.actions.invoker.InstallActionInvoker.invokeActions(InstallActionInvoker.java:16)
   at com.ibm.ws.install.config.actions.invoker.InstallActionInvoker.main(InstallActionInvoker.java:30)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:45)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)
   at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.launchMain(WSLauncher.java:213)
   at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.main(WSLauncher.java:93)
   at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.run(WSLauncher.java:74)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformActivator$1.run(PlatformActivator.java:78)
   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:92)
   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:68)
   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:177)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:45)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)
   at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:340)
   at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:282)
   at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:981)
   at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.launchEclipse(WSPreLauncher.java:330)
   at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.main(WSPreLauncher.java:108)
Task stopped for: wsadmin - FAILURE
Target stopped for: generateProfileKey - FAILURE
Exception was thrown, type of exception is: class org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException
The exception message is: wsadmin task failed with return code :-1
The translated exception message is: wsadmin task failed with return code :-1
The stack trace follows
/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profileTemplates/cell/dmgr/actions/generateProfileKey.ant:26: wsadmin task failed with return code :-1
Build stopped - FAILURE
Result of executing /usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profileTemplates/cell/dmgr/actions/generateProfileKey.ant was: false
Configuration action failed: com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ConfigAction-/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profileTemplates/cell/dmgr/actions/generateProfileKey.ant
Fatal configuration action failed: com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ConfigAction-/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profileTemplates/cell/dmgr/actions/generateProfileKey.ant
ConfigManager action execution failed on a fatal action
Returning with return code: INSTCONFFAILED
Creation of profile Dmgr01 at path /usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/Dmgr01 failed.
Unregistering profile Dmgr01
Adding this file to the system JVM classpath: /usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profileTemplates/cell/dmgr/lib/cell_dmgrResource.jar
Adding this URL to the system JVM classpath: file:/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profileTemplates/cell/dmgr/lib/cell_dmgrResource.jar
Adding this file to the system JVM classpath: /usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profileTemplates/cell/dmgr/lib/cell_dmgrResource.jar
Adding this URL to the system JVM classpath: file:/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profileTemplates/cell/dmgr/lib/cell_dmgrResource.jar
Adding this file to the system JVM classpath: /usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profileTemplates/cell/dmgr/lib/cell_dmgrResource.jar
Adding this URL to the system JVM classpath: file:/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profileTemplates/cell/dmgr/lib/cell_dmgrResource.jar
Adding this file to the system JVM classpath: /usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profileTemplates/cell/dmgr/lib/cell_dmgrResource.jar
Adding this URL to the system JVM classpath: file:/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profileTemplates/cell/dmgr/lib/cell_dmgrResource.jar
Adding this file to the system JVM classpath: /usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profileTemplates/cell/dmgr/lib/cell_dmgrResource.jar
Adding this URL to the system JVM classpath: file:/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profileTemplates/cell/dmgr/lib/cell_dmgrResource.jar
Dmgr01:/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/Dmgr01:falsetrue and Dmgr01:/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/Dmgr01:falsetrue are equal
The script path for this profile: Dmgr01:/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/Dmgr01:falsetrue, is: /usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/properties/fsdb/Dmgr01.sh
Deleted profile: Dmgr01:/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/Dmgr01:falsetrue from the FS DB
Resetting the system properties to remove custom properties
INSTCONFFAILED: The profile could not be created.  For more information, consult the /usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/logs/manageprofiles/Dmgr01_create.log file.
Finished Execution: result:1
Returning with return code: INSTCONFFAILED
```

Comment: Try attaching to it with strace to see what it's stuck on. Do something like: strace -s 512 -f -p pidof_installer_or_children_here 2>&1| tee /tmp/installer1.strace

Comment: That attaches a special debugger that only prints out system calls. If you see an error it has a good likelyhood of being the problem. If you just see a lot of selects() then it's waiting for some data. If you restart the install you can start strace from the beginning. Anyway if its not the main process, check if the main installer is spawning any children.

Comment: Also some cryptographic programs (like pgp) generate their own random numbers which can take a while.

Comment: Last thing - check if the installer leaves a log somewhere. A lot of installers log their progress.

Comment: OP updated. I'll try something new in a moment.

Comment: Also, I don't think it's a matter of slow entropy generation because I made sure to check `/proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail/` and it wasn't low values all the time (e.g. there was always entropy on the kernel's RNG pool).